# Plotting function in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I am trying to plot the following function:

[image: function]

Where x=(x-floor(x))

This is what I have written in my .tex-file:

```
\draw[color=blue,smooth] plot({\x-floor(\x)},{\frac{\cos(\frac{\pi}{6})}{ \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}\{\frac{3*\x}{\pi}\}-\frac{\pi}{6})}});
```

But this returns a vast amount of errors I quite frankly doesnt understand.

It should look like something like this (curve to the right):
[image]

Comment: Maybe post the errors? Also consider giving us a minimal working example so we know what documentclass you are using. Any other information like which version of LaTeX are you working with would be helpful as well!

Comment: As the function is not smooth, you probably better draw the three arcs one by one by restricting the domains. Otherwise, you will get a "smooth" result without nice kinks.

Comment: `\frac`, `\cos`, `\pi` are typesetting commands, they are not supported in `pgfmath` expressions. Instead use operator `/` and functions `cos` and `pi`. without backslash. Also the default for trigonometric functions is degrees, not radians.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters you should think about the function, it can be reduced considerably. Specifically, cos(pi/6) = 1; also in the denominator you have pi/3 * (3*x/pi), that term simplifies to x.

Additionally, since you are not trying to *typeset* the equation, but rather evaluate the equation you can do away with the `\frac` and `\cos` macros.

I've used a `\foreach` loop to draw the curve as many times as you want. I've also automated drawing the axis ticks on the x axis. Note that by including an 'r' within the `cos` I've told the function to see the units as radians.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw (0, 1.4cm ) -- (0,0) -- (4cm, 0);
        \draw [dotted] (0,1cm) -- (3.5 cm, 1cm);
        \draw [dotted] (0,1.155cm) -- (3.5 cm, 1.155cm);
        \draw (0, 0.15cm) --++(0,-0.30cm) node [below] {$0^\circ$};

        \foreach \y in {0,...,2}{
            \draw ({(pi/3) * (\y+1)}, 0.15cm) --++(0,-0.30cm) node [below] {$\number\numexpr(\y + 1)* 60\relax^\circ$};
            \begin{scope}
                [domain=0:(pi / 3)]
                \draw plot({\x + (pi/3) * \y},{ 1 /  cos(\x r - (pi r)/6)});
            \end{scope}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Running the above gives the following output:

[image: repeating plot]

Comment: Thank you very much! This was more than I could hope for :)

Comment: Don't forget that you can and should [*accept* the answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/1853/80176) that best solves the question! Our reputations depend on it.

Answer (score 2):

Drawing functions with `pgfplots` (should be the same with `TikZ`) uses a different syntax than what you are used to when writing functions in LaTeX. Have a look at section 4.3.3 in the [pgfplots manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf).

So here is an example of your function with `pgfplots`. Not perfect yet, but you should be able to finish it yourself. (I canceled the `pi` and the `3` by the way.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ymin=0.45, ymax=1.05]
        \addplot[blue,domain=0:pi,samples=1000] {cos(deg(pi/6))/cos(deg(x-floor(x)-pi/6))};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```